# customer journey map vs customer experience map

Tags: user-journey, customer-experience

can you tell me about the difference between customer journey map and customer experience map?

in Mapping Experience Book By James Kalbach he said they are two different things but i could not understand the differences and which one should i use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A customer journey map is a subset of a customer experience map which includes many other information like opportunities, pain points, calls to action, qualitative insight, why does each touchpoint exist from an operations perspective, what department  is responsible for each touchpoint, does each touchpoint enhance or weaken a customer’s experience etc.

According to this [article](http://adaptivepath.org/ideas/the-anatomy-of-an-experience-map/):

> It’s an artifact that serves to illuminate the complete experience a
>   person may have with a product or service. But it’s not just about the
>   illustration of the journey (that would simply be a journey map). And
>   it’s not a service blueprint which shows how a system works in enough
>   detail to verify, implement and maintain it.

And according to this [article](http://touchpointdashboard.com/2011/08/what-is-a-customer-touchpoint-or-journey-map/) :

> will help you better understand your customers and your business.  It
>   will help you strengthen customer relationships and see how all of
>   your touchpoints affect your bottom line so you can ultimately improve
>   it.

Comment: when should we use customer journey map and when should we use experience map?

Comment: depends from the scope of the project initiated. If deeper restructure of the service is needed then a user experience map might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I found this [great article by Jim Tincher](http://When%20deciding%20on%20the%20two,%20it%E2%80%99s%20critical%20to%20understand%20the%20business%20problem.%20We%20shortcut%20that%20to:%20Do%20you%20know%20the%20sources%20of%20most%20of%20your%20customer%20friction?%20A%20customer%20journey%20map%20is%20the%20right%20tool%20if%20you%20know%20where%20you%20want%20to%20focus.%20For%20example,%20we%20worked%20with%20an%20east%20coast%20hospital%20to%20better%20understand%20its%20radiology%20experience.%20By%20focusing%20on%20one%20specific%20journey%20(scheduling%20through%20receiving%20advanced%20imaging),%20we%20were%20able%20to%20give%20very%20specific%20feedback%20on%20where%20their%20patients%20were%20getting%20frustrated%20today,%20and%20where%20to%20target%20to%20build%20better%20patient%20outcomes%20and%20loyalty.%20But%20it%20was%20almost%20no%20help%20to%20other%20departments%20in%20the%20hospital.%20An%20experience%20map%20is%20best%20if%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20know%20exactly%20where%20the%20problem%20is.%20A%20non-profit%20client%20knew%20that%20friction%20occurred%20somewhere%20in%20their%20multi-year%20experience%20that%20led%20members%20to%20become%20less%20engaged,%20but%20didn%E2%80%99t%20know%20exactly%20where.%20Zeroing%20in%20on%20only%20one%20journey%20within%20that%20relationship%20would%20have%20caused%20us%20to%20miss%20members%E2%80%99%20most%20critical%20needs.%20The%20trade%20off%20is%20that%20while%20we%20had%20very%20actionable%20results%20that%20led%20to%20them%20to%20rethink%20everything%20from%20how%20they%E2%80%99re%20structured%20to%20their%20membership%20approach,%20we%20now%20need%20to%20zero%20in%20to%20get%20more%20specific%20on%20the%20member%20experience%20within%20specific%20journeys.), making the two quite clear. He states:

" When deciding on the two, it’s critical to understand the business problem. We shortcut that to: *Do you know the sources of most of your customer friction?*

A **customer journey map** is the right tool if you know where you want to focus. For example, we worked with an east coast hospital to better understand its radiology experience. By focusing on one specific journey (scheduling through receiving advanced imaging), we were able to give very specific feedback on where their patients were getting frustrated today, and where to target to build better patient outcomes and loyalty. But it was almost no help to other departments in the hospital.

An **experience map** is best if you don’t know exactly where the problem is. A non-profit client knew that friction occurred somewhere in their multi-year experience that led members to become less engaged, but didn’t know exactly where. Zeroing in on only one journey within that relationship would have caused us to miss members’ most critical needs. The trade off is that while we had very actionable results that led to them to rethink everything from how they’re structured to their membership approach, we now need to zero in to get more specific on the member experience within specific journeys."

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

A **customer journey** map covers the path from discovery of a need/desire through to finding brands and products appropriate, to purchase. It's the journey up to becoming a customer.

A **customer experience** map includes the above, but also continues through ownership, usage, service, support, recommendations, reviews, references, responses and referrals. It's the full experience of a customer, including how they are perceived as a customer, and how they feel about their peers, friends and family also becoming customers and users.

Comment: Becoming a customer is just one journey these map exercises can examine. The decision to make a purchase is key, but another moment that really matters is your first bad experience as a customer. What went wrong? The same exercise can be used to examine the "Unhappy customer" journey and look at the opportunities there.

Answer (score 1):

From
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ux-mapping-cheat-sheet/

**Customer Journey Mapping**
Customer journey maps focus on a specific customer’s interaction with a product or service.

**Experience Map**
Experience maps generalize the concept of customer-journey maps across user types and products.

Answer (score 1):

Since we are talking about customer experience maps and customer journey maps, I'd like to introduce some entropy here by talking about **service blueprints**, and the conversation kinda feels incomplete if we don't bring them up.

A good differentiation is mentioned in this article: https://www.freshtilledsoil.com/user-experience-maps-vs-service-blueprints/

Here is a summary: 
**Service blueprints** are one layer above customer experience maps and are internal facing. However, apart from looking at customer journey(s), they consider several tiers of actions provided by the organization offering the product or service including front-stage actions, backstage actions, and supporting services. By considering what actions different functional teams would have to take up, it helps to better organize which team is able to best tackle a pain point/ ease the process in the customer experience.

Answer (score 0):

A customer journey map focuses on the touchpoints (i.e., the interaction points between customer-brand and customer-customer) at all stages of the customer journey. It could be a linear process or it could be a loop, as well explained in [this article](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F0022242920920262).

When working on the experience map, the focus should be on the key factors/dimensions that customers care about when forming their experiential perceptions. Customer experience perceptions are contextual; meaning, the focal experiential factors are different in different situations. For instance, this article discusses the nine primary factors of [omnichannel customer experience](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jretai.2022.03.003). The factors would be different in other evaluative situations such as tourists' experiences of a city.